# Why is Python function returning wrong values?

Tags: python, python-3.7

My function returns wrong values when called.
First, iteration returns correct value but then if I call a new function. Why is it returning non-empty lists?

I ran the below code in my shell. The second last call should return an empty list but it returns the value return in the call before that.

```py
>>> from solvers.algorithms.dancing_links import solve
>>> solve({}, {})
[]
>>> solve(ctor, rtoc)
['B', 'D', 'F']
>>> solve(ctor, rtoc)
['B', 'D', 'F']
>>> solve({}, {})
['B', 'D', 'F']
```

This is my python code.

```py
# Solves the Sudoku using dancing links algorithm using implementation from:
# https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html


def solve(columns_to_rows, rows_to_columns, solution=[]):
    """
    This function solves the exact cover problem, i.e., given a matrix A in which each element is 0 or 1.
    Is there a subset of rows which have exactly one 1 in each column?
    The exact cover problem can also be stated as following,
    "Given a set X and a set of subsets of X called Y, is there a subset of Y such that all of its elements
    are disjoint and union of its elements is X."
    :param columns_to_rows: It is a dictionary where value of key `i` is the set of columns in which ith row is 1.
    :param rows_to_columns: It is a dictionary where value of key `i` is the set of rows in which ith column is 1.
    :param solution: Currently selected rows
    :return:
    """
    if not columns_to_rows:
        return list(solution)
    else:
        # Column with minimum 1's in it.
        selected_column = min(columns_to_rows, key=lambda col: columns_to_rows[col])
        # For each row which has a 1 in the `selected_column`.
        for selected_row in columns_to_rows[selected_column]:
            solution.append(selected_row)
            # Select and remove all columns which have 1's in the `selected_row`
            # Also remove all the rows which have 1's in the same column as the `selected_row`
            removed_columns = select_and_remove(columns_to_rows, rows_to_columns, selected_row)
            tmp = solve(columns_to_rows, rows_to_columns, solution)
            if tmp is not None:
                return tmp
            deselect_and_insert(columns_to_rows, rows_to_columns, selected_row, removed_columns)
            solution.pop()
```

Edit 1:
I added a print statement to print the "solution" variable and I found this.

```py
>>> from solvers.algorithms.dancing_links import solve>>> solve({}, {})
[]
[]
>>> solve({}, {})
[]
[]
>>> solve(ctor, rtoc)
[]
['A']
['B']
['B', 'D']
['B', 'D', 'F']
['B', 'D', 'F']
>>> solve({}, {})
['B', 'D', 'F']
['B', 'D', 'F']
>>>
```

So the first time I call the function it returns empty list and solution is also empty.
Then when I call the function second time with actual parameters it works as expected and goes into a recursive call.
But the third time the solution variable is already set to the previous value but it should be empty. 
Why is it happening? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass `solution=[]` to function, its saves it reference and can affect you resulsts, pass a new list everytime the function is running

more inforamtion: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Thank you, I would have wrecked my brain for hours before getting to know this.

Comment: Yes, this is the duplicate.